# CSS custom cursors for rotation

Tags: html, css

I know you can define some custom cursors in CSS like the re-size cursors and such, but I am trying to use the "rotate" cursors for the four different corners.  The ones that are bent at a 90 degree depending on what corner you are hovering over.

Any ideas how to do this in CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add invisible divs to your corners and define custom cursor for each div. The useful article: http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

Example with crossbrowser code:

```
cursor: url(cursor.cur),url(cursor/cursor.cur),default;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of the basic cursor style in css work in CSS2 (IE 4+) and there are CSS3 cursor too.

http://www.worldtimzone.com/mozilla/testcase/css3cursors.html